# increase performance of large csv file parsing in php-cli

Tags: php, mysql, performance, parsing, csv

Good evening, I have a csv file of 400mb and I have to load it in a mysql database. the csv file is "irregular" because it contains information such as:

```
user|email|password\n
user|password|otherdata\n
```

I have made a script in php-cli to read the file line by line and take the information I need: username and password. l 'username is always the first record. to know what 'is the password I look at the length of the string.

I run the script five hours ago and still has not finished loading all the data in the database.

how can I do to improve the performance of this script?

```
<?php

$fileHandle = fopen("C:/Users/AT/Documents/Backup/forumusers.csv", "r");

$mysqlHandle = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("testbackupboard");

while(!feof($fileHandle))
{
    $fileRow = fgets($fileHandle);
    $line2Record = explode("|", $fileRow);
    foreach ($line2Record as $rowRecord)
    {
        if (strlen($rowRecord) == 40)
        {
            $datatoMysql[0] = $rowRecord; // password hash
        }
    }
    $datatoMysql[1] = $line2Record[0]; // username

    $execQuery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO forumusers (username, hash) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string(utf8_encode($datatoMysql[1]))."', '".mysql_real_escape_string(utf8_encode($datatoMysql[0]))."')");
    if($execQuery)
    {
        print"Record ".$rowRecord[1]." ".$rowRecord[0]." loaded into db\n";
    }
    else
    {
        die(mysql_error());
    }
}
fclose($fileHandle);

?>
```

Comment: Rule #1: If possible, use MYSQL's LOAD DATA INFILE

Comment: Rule #2: If using PHP, then use PHP's built-in fgetcsv() function rather than fgets() and explode()

Comment: Rule #3: If using PHP, you shouldn't be hunting for a password hash based on the length of the value, it should be a specific column that's always identifiably... so don't waste effort reducing your row to a 2 entry array, just use the relevant columns from the fgetcsv() array in your SQL

Comment: @Mark Baker: Better make an answer, instead of multiple comments. At AntonioT: There are many ways to improve this. One of the quickest is to use one INSERT to insert multiple rows into the database. You can speed things up almost by the factor of rows you insert at one time.

Answer (score 0):

How about [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)()?

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "|")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `CREATE TABLE tmp` with 4 columns: `id` AUTO_INCREMENT, `user`, `col2`, `col3`.  This is not the final table.
2. `LOAD DATA` for all the rows
3. `CREATE TABLE final (user, email, password, otherdata, PRIMARY KEY(user))`
4. Then do

> ```
> INSERT INTO final (user, email, password, otherdata)
>     SELECT a.user, a.col2 AS email, a.col3 AS password,
>            b.col3 AS otherdata
>         FROM tmp AS a
>         JOIN tmp AS b ON b.id = a.id+1
>         WHERE (a.id % 2) = 1;
> ```
>
> (Caveat:  This will not work if `auto_increment_increment` is not 1, such as on a Galera-based cluster.  Instead, you would need an `@variable` to do the sequencing.)